# How to sum up to reach a number by date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make a formula that to do a sum calculation, that confirm which date to start (cell D5), then look for the start point from the row 1, and sum up the row 2 start from the correct date, and then stop the sum up if the amount is equal to or larger than run estimate (cell D6)

the steps should be like this:

1. I know the start day is 31-May
2. then I look into the table to find the date 31-May
3. then I look into the table again, find out the run estimate is 2 hours
4. I know I have 6 hours run estimate need to be completed
5. then I add 2 + 3 + 4 = 9 hours to cover the 6-hour estimate
6. then I know the end date is 2- Jun

I am able to find the start point on the table
=SUMIFS(B2:F2,B1:F1,">="&D5)
but I am not sure how to stop it
and moreover I am not sure how display the final value date, not the total amount..

```
    col B   col C          col D   col E   col F
    30-May  31-May         1-Jun    2-Jun   3-Jun
    1        2             3        4        5
                
                
            start date      31-May      
            run estimate    6       
                
expected result should be   2-Jun
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TwqH.png)
anyone can help on this?

Comment: It is unclear what you want exactly, and what the 6 means (days i assume?) And why does 6 then results in june 2? Can you show the data in an excel sheet (print screen would be fine)

Comment: hi @JanWillem, thanks for the comment, I have added the image in the content, please try and see if you can open it.
I have added the step 1 - 6 on the description, hope it look better now

Comment: So if the run estimate would be 10, then the result would be june 3? The sum of the run times must be greater than the run estimate

Comment: hi @JanWillem yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that requires one extra row of data, to calculate the sum of run times up until that day: Put this formula in cells B3:F3 (or however many columns you have exactly)

```
=SUMIF($B1:B1,">="&$D6,$B2:B2)
```

Then you can find the first value that is equal to or higher than your estimate runtime and use that to offset to the correct date:

```
=OFFSET(B1,0,IFERROR(MATCH($D6,B3:F3,0)-1,MATCH($D6,B3:F3,1)))
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi JanWillem, thanks for the help, I have tried the formula but my result looks a little bit difference as yours, I guess the formula shall be =OFFSET(B1,0,MATCH($D7,B3:F3,1)), correct?

Comment: $D6 in my answer is the run estimate value. In your sheet you have added a row, so your run estimate is now $D7

Comment: by the way, I found that if the run estimate = 9, end date will be 3-Jun, can it be 2-Jun ? because 2+3+4 exactly = 9 which can cover the run estimate

Comment: I will edit the formula to deal with this case